# Proper way to restore a default contextmenu for an edit control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, inheritance, contextmenu

I'm in a situation where I want to decide whether to disable or enable the default edit contextmenu of a subclassed `TextBox` control, I've written this:

```
Public Property DisableEditMenu As Boolean = False

''' <summary>
''' Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.Enter"/> event.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(e As EventArgs)

    If Me.DisableEditMenu AndAlso MyBase.ContextMenuStrip Is Nothing Then
        ' Disable Copy/Cut/Paste contextmenu by creating a new empty one.
        MyBase.ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip

    ElseIf Not Me.DisableEditMenu Then
        ' Restore default edit contextmenu...

    End If

    MyBase.OnEnter(e)

End Sub
```

The problem is... how I can restore the default contextmenu?

I've thinked about to solve it in this way, and it works ok, but I'm not sure if I'm being efficient or I'm doing unnecesary things than what i really should do to restore the default menu:

```
...
ElseIf Not Me.DisableEditMenu Then
    ' Restore default edit contextmenu...
    Using tb As New TextBox
        MyBase.ContextMenuStrip = tb.ContextMenuStrip
    End Using
...
```

Because **.Net Framework Class Library** provides a reference for default values, such as default control colors (eg: `TextBox.DefaultBackColor`), then maybe a default edit contextmenu is contained/referred in some `Type` that I didn't discovered yet? or to restore it efficientlly is more hard than I imagine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *"restore the default contextmenu"*, set the `ContextMenuStrip` property to null.

```
Me.ContextMenuStrip = Nothing
```

However, there's no need to set the `ContextMenu` to a new empty instance. All you have to do is to suppress the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes this message as:

> *Notifies a window that the user clicked the right mouse button (right-clicked) in the window.*

```
Public Class UITextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Public Property DisableEditMenu As Boolean

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If ((m.Msg = WM_CONTEXTMENU) AndAlso Me.DisableEditMenu) Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Const WM_CONTEXTMENU As Integer = 123

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, I know the alternatives, but I use my way on that to avoid unnecessary windows message interception and processing to don't charge the control with much more operations than what it really needs (I'm in some way a performance obsessive but anyways I'm not any expert on performance). I only would like to know the answer of the question that I did, but really thankyou anyways to try to help me!

Comment: But my intention is to restore it after I set to Nothing the contextmenu! :-/, thanks for comment.

Comment: Huh? The default menu will be used if you set the `ContextMenuStrip` property to null. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: yes, i understood bad your last comment I thinked that you mean set it to Nothing to disable it not to re-enable it, sorry was my fault!